# android : login gmail with oauth is not asking for user id or password

Tags: android, oauth, gmail

In my app i am loggint in to my google account using oauth and i am retrieving all the user account details. The issue is that since i am always logged on to my primary gmail account , my app is taking that as the user account. It never prompts for user login  / password. So i am not able to try getting the account details of any other gmail id.

how can i force to ask for email and password even if the user is already logged in.
My request token code is given below

```
public class RequestTokenActivity extends Activity {


ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private OAuthConsumer consumer; 
private OAuthProvider provider;
private SharedPreferences prefs;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i("create","create");

    try {
        consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(C.CONSUMER_KEY, C.CONSUMER_SECRET);
        provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(
                C.REQUEST_URL  + "?scope=" + URLEncoder.encode(C.SCOPE, C.ENCODING) + "&xoauth_displayname=" + C.APP_NAME,
                C.ACCESS_URL,
                C.AUTHORIZE_URL);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(C.TAG, "Error creating consumer / provider",e);
    }

    //getRequestToken();
    new OAuthRequestTokenTask(this,consumer,provider).execute();
}


@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.i("newin","newintent");
    super.onNewIntent(intent); 
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final Uri uri = intent.getData();
    if (uri != null && uri.getScheme().equals(C.OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME)) {
        Log.i(C.TAG, "Callback received : " + uri);
        Log.i(C.TAG, "Retrieving Access Token");
        getAccessToken(uri);
    }
    else {
        new OAuthRequestTokenTask(this,consumer,provider).execute();
    }
}

private void getRequestToken() {
    try {
        Log.d(C.TAG, "getRequestToken() called");
        String url = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, C.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
        this.startActivity(intent);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(C.TAG, "Error retrieving request token", e);
    }
}

private void getAccessToken(Uri uri) {
    final String oauth_verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);
    try {
        provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, oauth_verifier);

        final Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.putString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, consumer.getToken());
        edit.putString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, consumer.getTokenSecret());
        edit.commit();

        String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
        String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");

        consumer.setTokenWithSecret(token, secret);
        this.startActivity(new Intent(this ,OAuthMain.class));

        Log.i(C.TAG, "Access Token Retrieved");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(C.TAG, "Access Token Retrieval Error", e);
    }
}
public class OAuthRequestTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    final String TAG = getClass().getName();
    private Context context;
    private OAuthProvider provider;
    private OAuthConsumer consumer;

    /**
     * 
     * We pass the OAuth consumer and provider.
     * 
     * @param   context
     *          Required to be able to start the intent to launch the browser.
     * @param   provider
     *          The OAuthProvider object
     * @param   consumer
     *          The OAuthConsumer object
     */
    public OAuthRequestTokenTask(Context context,OAuthConsumer consumer,OAuthProvider provider) {
        this.context = context;
        this.consumer = consumer;
        this.provider = provider;
    }
 @Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
     progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(RequestTokenActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    progressDialog.setMessage(" Loading ...");
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.setProgress(0);
    progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

        public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) 
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            finish();

        }
    });

    progressDialog.show();

}
    /**
     * 
     * Retrieve the OAuth Request Token and present a browser to the user to authorize the token.
     * 
     */
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "Retrieving request token from Google servers");
            final String url = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, C.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
            Log.i(TAG, "Popping a browser with the authorize URL : " + url);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
            context.startActivity(intent);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error during OAUth retrieve request token", e);
        }

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is not your code, but your browser settings.

With

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)).setFlags(
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
    | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

you are calling an external browser to open Google's authorization page. If the user is already logged in to Google in that browser, he will just be asked to approve your application. If he was not logged in already, he will first be presented with the login screen. So just log out there and you can log in as another user.

Instead of relying on an external browser, you could also open your own [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). If you don't implement cookie management yourself for the web view, the user will *always* be asked to login there.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I am yet to try it. But i think it should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably refrain from asking a password from the end user, however if you would like to prompt the user on what email account to use (it could be one already registered with the device in question, or a new one), you may start an account picker intent.

Sample pseudo code:

```
//Applicable only to Google accounts for now.
        String[] accountTypes = new String[]{"com.google"};
        Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, //There is no currently selected account.
                                                             null, //There is no restricted list of accounts.
                                                             accountTypes, //The dialog should list only accounts from the "com.google" domain.
                                                             true, //prompt the user to pick an account if there's only one available account (just use that one). Even if only one account currently exists, the dialog may include an option for the user to add a new account.
                                                             null, //There is no custom title for the dialog.
                                                             null, //There is no specific auth token type required.
                                                             null, //There are no restrictions based on account features.
                                                             null); //There are no authenticator-specific options.

        //Capture end-users account selection and proceed with SignIn. onActivityResult() will be called once the user has made their selection.
        startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode); //This will initiate a dialog.
```

Once startActivityForResult() has retunred, i.e., user has made their selection, you could retrieve the chosen email address in the following way:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case <the request code you passed to startActivityForResult:
                // Receiving a result from the AccountPicker
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        //Retrieve the chosen email account
                        data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME));
                    } else {
                        //Handle error
                    }
                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    // The account picker dialog closed without selecting an account.
                    // Notify users that they must pick an account to proceed.
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Note that the end user is not restricted on what account the opt for by using the AccountManager. After all, they can always go with Add Account option once the intent dialog appears.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!